# Lighttpd: how to rewrite the URI before passing to uwsgi?

Tags: uwsgi, lighttpd

I have a wsgi app running under Lighttpd. The entire API is registered under `/forms` but that's a local configuration.

```
server.modules += ( "mod_scgi" )
scgi.debug = 7
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/forms" {
    scgi.protocol = "uwsgi"
    scgi.server   = ( "/" => 
        ((
            "host" => "localhost",
            "port" => 8000,
            "fix-root-scriptname" => "enable",
            "check-local" => "disable",    
        ))
    )
}
```

My goal is to NOT make uwsgi aware of the /forms prefix, ie it should be agnostic regarding the global configuration so I can change it without changing the code.

For example, as a toy handler I would have to write this:

```
@app.route('/forms')
def index():
    return "<span style='color:red'>I am app 1</span>"
```

But if I later change the the lighttpd.conf setting, I would have also to setup the uwsgi accordingly, which I don't want to.

However mod_rewrite does not work inside the `$HTTP["url"]` section so I am at a loss of how to accomplish that.

Ideally I would not like to change `uwsgi.ini` as well. Ideas?

Comment: Why is any of this necessary?  If you want your app to be path-agnostic, then write your app to be path-agnostic, using relative paths.  Separately, if you want to maintain "/forms" in exactly one place, then create a shell script config file that sets environment variables, and source that before starting lighttpd (and have lighttpd.conf use the environment variable containing the path "/forms"), and do something similar in your uwsgi script.

Comment: [mod_rewrite](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/mod_rewrite) does work inside lighttpd `$HTTP["url"]` conditions.  It sounds like you have not configured it well.